# How to mockk Android Databinding BR for unit tests JUnit5

Tags: android, junit, junit5, mockk

I have a view model that performs an action like below while initialization

```
class MyViewModel(someClass: SomeClass): ViewModel() {
    
    @get:Bindable
    private var loading: Boolean = false
        set(loading) {
            field = loading
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.loading)
        }
    
    init {
        loading = true
    }
}
```

I am writing unit tests with JUnit5 using mockk

```
class MyViewModelTest {
    private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel
    private lateinit var someClass: SomeClass
    
    @BeforeEach
    fun beforeEach() {
        someClass = mockk()
        viewModel = MyViewModel()
    }
}
```

I am getting error on this line `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.loading)`. The error is

```
path/to/the/BR
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: path/to/the/BR
    at MyViewModel.setLoading(MyViewModel.kt:15)
```

I am clueless what to do. I tried mocking the BR but keep getting the error that `couldn't resolve class BR.`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? im having the same issue but it is only a problem in the library modules, in the main app module the generated BR class is found during unitttests

Comment: @JoachimHaglund Nope unfortunately!

Comment: i got around it by moving all the testclasses that used ui resources to the main app module, which isnt how i would ideally have it organized because the testmodule for app is now huge, but at least it works

Comment: yeah that's the only way. It's unfortunate because the whole point for me was to move my test cases to the module they belong but now they are all in the the main module.